# Renaming tables in DB in code first approach

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have database and multiple tables inside , I am using EF code first approach in my project.

At some point I need to change the names of some or maybe all tables in database.

What is the best way to implement it in code first approach?

Comment: Decorate your entities with `[Table]` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) or set the mapping explicitly using FluentApi (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.3).

Answer (score 5):

You need to rename tables with migrations, i.e.

```
public override void Up()
{
    RenameTable("MyOldTableName", "MyNewTableName");
}

public override void Down()
{
    RenameTable("MyNewTableName", "MyOldTableName");
}
```

Then you need to change the table name on the mapping. If you use data annotation you can specify the table name with Table attribute

```
[Table("MyNewTableName")]
class MyEntity
{
    // props
}
```

If you use fluent interace

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyNewTableName");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will change the table your entity maps to.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
}
```

Comment: Be aware that changing your table names could cause your migrations to drop the table first before creating the table with the new name.